How to assign scores to each value in pandas columns based on percentile range, getting `Truth value of a Series is ambiguous.` error
I need to assign scores to each of the values in many columns of a pandas dataframe, depending on the percentile score range each value falls between.
I have created a function:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def get_percentiles(x, percentile_array):
    percentile_array = np.sort(np.array(percentile_array))
    if x < x.quantile(percentile_array[0]) < 0:
        return 1
    elif (x >= x.quantile(percentile_array[0]) & (x < x.quantile(percentile_array[1]):
        return 2
    elif (x >= x.quantile(percentile_array[1]) & (x < x.quantile(percentile_array[2]):
        return 3
    elif (x >= x.quantile(percentile_array[2]) & (x < x.quantile(percentile_array[3]):
        return 4
    else:
        return 5

Sample data:
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1' : [1,10,5,9,15,4],
                   'col2' : [4,10,15,19,3,2],
                   'col3' : [10,5,6,9,1,24]})

When I try to run the function using apply:
percentile_array = [0.05, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75]

df.apply(lambda x : get_percentiles(x, percentile_array), result_type = 'expand')

I get below error:
Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

The expected output is new dataframe with 3 columns that has the scores between 1 and 5 depending on which percentile range each value in each column falls under

IIUC, you could use rank to compute the percentile (per column), then pandas.cut to bin the values to your reference:
percentile_array = [0.05, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75]
bins = [-np.inf]+percentile_array+[np.inf]
labels = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

out = (df.rank(pct=True)
         .apply(lambda c: pd.cut(c, bins=bins, labels=labels))
      )

Alternatively, with numpy.searchsorted:
percentile_array = [0.05, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75]
bins = [-np.inf]+percentile_array+[np.inf]

out = pd.DataFrame(np.searchsorted(bins, df.rank(pct=True)),
                   columns=df.columns, index=df.index)

Output:
  col1 col2 col3
0    2    3    5
1    5    4    3
2    3    5    3
3    4    5    4
4    5    3    2
5    3    2    5

Intermediate:
df.rank(pct=True)

       col1      col2      col3
0  0.166667  0.500000  0.833333
1  0.833333  0.666667  0.333333
2  0.500000  0.833333  0.500000
3  0.666667  1.000000  0.666667
4  1.000000  0.333333  0.166667
5  0.333333  0.166667  1.000000

For the original function to work, you would have needed something like:
def get_percentiles(x, percentile_array):
    percentile_array = np.sort(np.array(percentile_array))
    m1 = x < x.quantile(percentile_array[0])
    m2 = (x >= x.quantile(percentile_array[0])) & (x < x.quantile(percentile_array[1]))
    m3 = (x >= x.quantile(percentile_array[1])) & (x < x.quantile(percentile_array[2]))
    m4 = (x >= x.quantile(percentile_array[2])) & (x < x.quantile(percentile_array[3]))

    return np.select([m1, m2, m3, m4], [1, 2, 3, 4], 5)


Thanks, could you please let me know what was wrong with my code, just want to understand why it didn't work

@KarthikS you can't use if/else with a vector, this would only work for a single value.

@KarthikS I'm updating the answer with a fix of your function (this gives a slightly different result, carefully check the boundaries of each condition).
